# How to grep a pattern in specific type of files in a directory

Tags: grep

I have a big directory that has a lot of CSS, JS, and PHP files. Some of these files exist in sub directories. I use this command to grep for files that contains a pattern recursively

```
grep -r <pattern> *
```

some times JS files occupies most of the screen, in this way.

Is there a simple way that can just grep PHP file, without using "find"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to specify `--include`:

```
grep -r --include '*.php' <pattern> .
```

The `--include` option takes a glob that can be used to specify the files to be searched:

```
   --include=GLOB
          Search  only  files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard
          matching as described under --exclude).
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -Hrn <pattern> *.php`

This will only search in file with `.php` extensions

-H will also give filename

n = will also show line number in file

r = recursive

Hope this helps

Comment: This command only search in current directory. I does not go in to sub dir.

Comment: The problem is that `*.php` would be expanded by the shell and then passed to `grep`, so it essentially implies passing a list of php files in the current directory to `grep`.

Comment: Got it..I thought you only want to scan current directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second `grep`:

```
grep -rH pattern * | grep '.php:'
```

But the best way would be `find` anyway:

```
find -name '*.php' -exec grep pattern {} \;
```